# Launch app from wear and get the message regardless the state of app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wear-os

I'm dealing with wearable, and my purpose is the next:

From my watch, I want to press a simple button, which send a simple message to the mobile. But I would like to handle all those behaviors :

- when mobile app isn't yet launched, then launch the app and pass the message from wear, which can be handled in the launcher activity
- when mobile app is launched but in the background, then just bring it to foreground and handle message from wear, which can be handled in the launcher activity
- when mobile app is launched and in foreground, juste handle the message in the launcher activity

So far, I handle to launch the app when it isn't not yet launched, but I can't get the *extra message* in the launcher activity contained in the *intent*. Here the code.

**the mobile service**

```
public class MobileWearService extends WearableListenerService {

    private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        String event = messageEvent.getPath();
        String msg = new String(messageEvent.getData());

        if (event.equals(START_ACTIVITY)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
            intent.putExtra("Data", msg);
            intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I use a broadcast to send the message from service to the main activity, it works only if the app is launched and foreground

```
   public class MobileWearService extends WearableListenerService {

        private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
            String event = messageEvent.getPath();
            String msg = new String(messageEvent.getData());

            if (event.equals(START_ACTIVITY)) {
                broadcastIntent.setAction("com.me.project.wear.to.app");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("Data", msg);
                broadcastIntent.putExtras(intent);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**launcher activity**

```
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.me.project.wear.to.app");
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("com.me.project.wear.to.app")) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Data");
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

So I would to combine the fact to get the message from wear (I know how to) but pass this message to get it in the launcher activity regardless of the state of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the static BroadcastReceiver

```
public class WatchMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null &&  
            intent.getAction().equals("com.me.project.wear.to.app")) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Data");
            Intent launcherIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);
            launcherIntent.putExtra("Data",msg);
            startActivity(launcherIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

in your manifest file

```
   <receiver android:name ="WatchMessageReceiver"
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.me.project.wear.to.app"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: But to retrieve the data message from the launcher activity, I guess it's in the resume method and by the getIntent() right? Because now the broadcast is well launched thanks to the static way, but I can't get the data because the bundle is null

Comment: It depends. If your launcher activity  launch mode is 'singleTask' then you have to override onNewIntent() in launcher activity. Else you can do getIntent() in onCreate(If launcher activity created again)

Comment: Ok I will deal with it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Sending and Syncing Data training](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html), there is a [Handling Data Layer Events](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html):

> When you make a call to the Data Layer API, you can receive the status of the call when it completes. You also can listen for data events, resulting from data changes that your application makes anywhere on the Android Wear network.

### Listen for Data Layer Events

> Because the data layer synchronizes and sends data across the handheld and wearable, it is usually necessary to listen for important events. Examples of such events include creation of data items and receipt of messages.
>
> To listen for data layer events, you have two options:
>
> - Create a service that extends WearableListenerService.
> - Create an activity that implements DataApi.DataListener.
>
> With both these options, you override the data event callback methods for the events you are interested in handling.

Some of the events you can listen for using [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) are as follows:

> - [**`onDataChanged()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onDataChanged(com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer)): Whenever a data item object is created, deleted, or changed, the system triggers this callback on all connected nodes.
> - [**`onMessageReceived()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onMessageReceived(com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent)): A message sent from a node triggers this callback on the target node.
> - [**`onCapabilityChanged()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html#onCapabilityChanged(com.google.android.gms.wearable.CapabilityInfo)): When a capability that an instance of your app advertises becomes available on the network, that event triggers this callback. If you're looking for a nearby node you can query the [**`isNearby()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node.html#isNearby()) method of the nodes provided in the callback.

According to the related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27132705/5995040):

> WearableListenerService does not run constantly - it is only started when a new message/node connection/data layer change is sent and stopped when there are no more messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to be a very good way to handle this too! Thanks for your help guys!